# $x$ is a positive integer with at least 2 digits, a perfect square, and its tens digit is odd. What are the possible units digits of x?

Tags: decimal-expansion, square-numbers

I have no idea where to start; and guess-and- check is all I can get up to now.

Comment: You mean to say $16,36..$ type of integers?

Comment: Well the tens digit is controlled by units and tens, anything larger won't effect it. So you can enumerate perfect squares up to at most 100, and check there. At the very least this reduces the amount of checking there is to do.

Comment: In fact I think the only answers are 1 and 6. If you look at all possible perfect squares, the units digit can only be 1,4,5,6,9,0. To rule out the others you just have to show that anything else would have an even tens digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(10a+b)^2=100a^2+20ab+b^2$$
where $b$ is a single digit number. So the tens digit is $2ab$ plus the carry-over from $b^2$. Since $2ab$ is even, the carry-over must be odd in order for the tens digit to be odd. The only possibilities for $b$ are therefore $b=4$ and $b=6$ as these are the only single-digit numbers whose square have an odd tens digit.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check the squares $\bmod 20$.  A quick spreadsheet shows that $6$ is the only possibility, coming from squaring $04, 06, 14, 16$  Another way to see it is that if the number squared is $10a+b$ the square is $100a^2+20ab+b^2$ so you need $b^2$ to have an odd tens digit and only $4,6$ do.